# Best way to transform PHP multiarray into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm porting an app from PHP to Javascript and I need to convert a big multiarray. I would like to know what would be the best structure/format since I believe there are a few ways of doing this.

The way the array will need to be accessed is both by selecting its subarrays by key (level_1, level_2, etc) and iterating over them to extract all their values using thir keys (type, units, num, etc).

This is a sample of the PHP array:

```
public $contents= array(
        'level_1' => array(
                array('type' => 'unit', 'units' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)),
                array('type' => 'review', 'num' => 1, 'txt' => 'Units 1-5'),
                array('type' => 'unit', 'units' => array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
                array('type' => 'review', 'num' => 2, 'txt' => 'Units 6-10'),
                array('type' => 'unit', 'units' => array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)),
                array('type' => 'review', 'num' => 3, 'txt' => 'Units 11-15'),
        ),
        'level_2' => array(
                array('type' => 'unit', 'units' => array(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)),
                array('type' => 'review', 'num' => 4, 'txt' => 'Units 16-20'),
                array('type' => 'unit', 'units' => array(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)),
                array('type' => 'review', 'num' => 5, 'txt' => 'Units 21-25'),
                array('type' => 'unit', 'units' => array(26, 27, 28, 29, 30)),
                array('type' => 'review', 'num' => 6, 'txt' => 'Units 26-30'),
        ),
        ...
}
```

EDIT

Just to clarify, I'm porting the app, so I need to re-declare that array in javascript, not call it from javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and then just put it in your view code.

PHP:

```
$contents = json_encode($contents);
```

and then in your javascript:

```
<script>
    var content = <?=$contents; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Note `<?=` might not work on all servers. Best to just use `<?php echo`

Comment: The 100% compatible version is `<?php echo $contents;?>`

Comment: The odds that those compatibility issues are relevant are small enough I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes :**

(1) You can encode your array using json_encode($array) from php.

(2) At Client side (i.e Javascript),you can decode that array.

**PHP :**

```
$data = json_encode($contents);
```

**Javascript :**

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```